# Can't keep Ghostscript from subsetting fonts

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript

I generated a PDF from a website using wkHTMLtoPDF, named `test3.pdf`.

`pdffonts` reports that the fonts are embedded ans not subsetted:

```
$ pdffonts test3.pdf
Config Error: No display font for 'Symbol'
Config Error: No display font for 'ZapfDingbats'
name                                 type              emb sub uni prob object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---- ---------
ArialRegular                         CID TrueType      yes no  yes          11  0
ArialBold                            CID TrueType      yes no  yes          40  0
TimesNewRomanRegular                 CID TrueType      yes no  yes          41  0
```

Afterwards I further processed the file with Ghostscript (9.06), explicitly telling it not to subset the fonts:

```
gswin64c.exe \
    -dPDFX \
    -dBATCH \
    -dNOPAUSE \
    -dNOPROMPT \
    -dNOOUTERSAVE \
    -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK \
    -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK \
    -sColorConversionStrategyForImages=CMYK \
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
    -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 \
    -sOutputICCProfile=Coated_Fogra39L_VIGC_300.icc \
    -dAutoFilterColorImages=false \
    -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false \
    -dDownsampleColorImages=false \
    -dDownsampleGrayImages=false \
    -dDownsampleMonoImages=false \
    -dCompressFonts=true \
    -dSubsetFonts=false \
    -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
    -sOutputFile=test3.ghost.pdf \
    PDFX4_def.ps \
    test3.pdf
```

The resulting `test3.ghost.pdf` however has subsetted fonts:

```
$ pdffonts test3.ghost.pdf
Config Error: No display font for 'Symbol'
Config Error: No display font for 'ZapfDingbats'
name                                   type              emb sub uni prob object ID
-------------------------------------- ----------------- --- --- --- ---- ---------
EFHOSN+TimesNewRomanRegular-Identity-H CID TrueType      yes yes yes          33  0
JXUCAA+ArialBold-Identity-H            CID TrueType      yes yes yes          29  0
HDZKQN+ArialRegular-Identity-H         CID TrueType      yes yes yes          15  0
```

I checked the source code and the (with QPDF uncompressed) font byte streams are actually much smaller than those from `test3.pdf`.

Apparently `-dSubsetFonts=false` does not work here...

Comment: First thing I would try is a version of Ghostscript less than 5 years old. The current version of Ghostscript is 9.23

Comment: If the size of the TrueType font exceeds an (undocumented) threshold then TrueType fonts are subset. I'm not sure why this is a problem for you, perhaps you could explain.

Comment: Echoing @KenS, since this is a derivative PDF, why are you turning off subsetting? Conversely, if you want to supply people with an editable document, why are you generating a PDF?

Comment: I tried 9.23, but the result was the same. Personally, I think just having the subset embedded shouldn't be a problem (since the PDF is only for printing). But my client says there can be (not further specified) problems with their printing controller with subsetting. And since wkHTMLtoPDF apparently doesn't subset, the fonts don't seem to exceed a threshold -- or is it Ghostscript-specific?